# I want to push / add object to the state react native (invalid attempt to spread non iterable instance)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i want to add object to my state and i have search to solve it but all of it doesn't work

```
this.state = {
   value : {name:'test'}
};
```

i want to add an object {coordinate:'0,0'} in this.state.value

> I tried this one but i got error : invalid attempt to spread non
>   iterable instance

```
let floors = [...this.state.value];
floors.push({ coordinate: '0,0'});
this.setState({ value:floors });
```

> I tried this one but i got error : invalid attempt to spread non
>   iterable instance

```
this.setState({
   value:[...this.state.value, {coordinate: '0,0'}]
});
```

> I tried this one but i got error : _this2.state.value.concat is not a
>   function

```
this.setState( {
   value: this.state.value.concat({koordinat:coor})
});
```

please help me to solve it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tried to spread a map into an array.

If you want to start with an array, then change your initial state:

```
this.state = { value: [{ name: 'test' }] }
```

Then you can use your original code, either of the first two examples.

Your second example fails for the same reason.

The third example doesn't make sense, you're trying to `concat` onto an object.

---

Based on the comments none of the original code really addressed what you are trying to do, namely, simply adding a property to an existing object. As schogges points out, this is trivial:

```
this.setState({
  value: { ...this.state.value, coordinate: '0, 0') }
})
```

This spreads an existing object into a new object with an additional property.

That said: coordinates aren't strings, they're objects.

Comment: i want to add object not array how is it?

Comment: then you should do: `this.setState({
   value: { ...this.state.value, coordinate: '0,0' }
});`

Comment: @RayCoder Then your code makes no sense--you're *explicitly* treating the state as an array or values in your last two examples--if you want to add a property to the object in state then just add it.